# Linking 2 libraries with same module name and subroutine name

Tags: fortran

I'm on a Fortran project, that I have to link 2 libraries who have same module name, under which, have same subroutine name.
I'm using Intel Fortran compiler, when I import the module and call the subroutine, it always goes to the first one linked.

Is there a way that I can specifically call a subroutine from a specific library?

Here's some pseudo code:

Lib1 and Lib 2 both have this:

```
module foo
  subroutine func()
    write (*, *) "Hello from Lib1" ! or Lib2
  end subroutine()
end module
```

Main

```
program Main
  use foo, only: func

  call func()
end program
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE libLib1.so libLib2.so)
```

Comment: I stand with @Vladimir F 's answer. If you have access to the source code of those two libraries, just change names, even because it is very strange you can link to two libraries who provide two indentically named modules.
That being said, if this is not possible for some reason, and if you have also the .dll version, there might be a turnaround, where you link statically to just one of the two, and you load the second dynamically, and get the desired function address at runtime, so that you can use either one of the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is illegal to have two modules name identically in Fortran. When writing libraries used by other users, I highly recommend to use prefixes such as `mylibrary_foo` for module names and other entities that might clash.

Now you cannot do much, apart from renaming the stuff. If you want to try to somehow separate the stuff using tricks in your toolchain, you firstly have to specify your toolchain in detail, but I'm sceptical.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We eventually use `-fvisibility-hidden` feature to hide the symbols that we do not want to import, meanwhile this doesn't affect the in-library symbol references.
Toolchain is Intel oneAPI 2021.